# How does "one-pass" authentication differ from "two-pass"?

Tags: block-cipher, authentication, mac, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation

The meaning of "one-pass authentication" as well as its difference from "two-pass authentication" has not been explained to my satisfaction. CCM mode, EAX mode, and HMAC are examples of the first type; OCB mode and GCM are examples of the second type. How do the two differ?

Suppose we have a block cipher mode of operation that has $\Phi$ and $F$. $\Phi$ is a value that is initialized to some value prior to encryption or decryption. $F$ is a function that takes $PT_i$ (a block of plaintext), $CT_i$ (a block of ciphertext), and $\Phi$ as parameters. After each encryption/decryption of a block of data, $\Phi$ is updated to equal $F(PT_i, CT_i, \Phi)$. After updating $\Phi$ for the last time, the message authentication code is calculated by encrypting $\Phi$. Is this a one-time mode of authentication? Is it as strong as the underlying block cipher?

Comment: What source calls OCB and GCM ‘two-pass’?  Are you sure you're not confusing GCM with, _e.g._, GCM-SIV, where every block of the key stream is a function of the entire message?

Comment: 'Is it as strong as the underlying block cipher?'; given that we don't know what $F$ is, I can't see how anyone can state that it definitely is.  It could be (GCM can be defined in this manner), but it might not be as well...

Comment: @poncho It can be whatever. To satisfy your question, just assume it is some variant of xorshift.